# Как явно обратиться к столбцам составного типа в Postgre?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть составной тип:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_well AS (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  altitude NUMERIC(10,3),
  x NUMERIC(10,6),
  y NUMERIC(10,6)
);
```

При использовании этого типа в запросах необходимо строго следовать порядку столбцов в определении. Если я буду пытаться передать переменную этого типа в функцию:

```sql
SELECT * FROM p_well_operations_new(1, ROW(1, 'bla', 42, 1.99, 3.45));
```

то нельзя менять порядок следования столбцов, иначе значения будут записаны неверно.

Как явно указать столбцы в составном типе? Это вообще возможно?

Как-то вот так к примеру:

```sql
SELECT * FROM p_well_operations_new(1, ROW(id=1, name='bla',...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксической такой конструкции нет. Но зато можно сделать свою функцию-конструктор, а вот параметры функции уже можно поимённо указывать в любом порядке:

```
CREATE TYPE t_well AS (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  altitude NUMERIC(10,3),
  x NUMERIC(10,6),
  y NUMERIC(10,6)
);

create function t_well(
  id INTEGER default null,
  name VARCHAR(10) default null,
  altitude NUMERIC(10,3) default null,
  x NUMERIC(10,6) default null,
  y NUMERIC(10,6) default null
)
returns t_well
as $function$
select row(id, name, altitude, x, y)::t_well
$function$ language sql;

select t_well(x => 20, y => 4.54, id => 7);
          t_well          
--------------------------
 (7,,,20.000000,4.540000)
```